# Django & Authorization Bearer Token

Tags: python, django, api, authorization, bearer-token

I'm working on Django for an app refrencial on job. I want to get data from an API Pole Emploi. I'm register on the web site, I got a client_id, client_secret etc.
I do a get request to get my access_token.

```
def login_explo_metier_pole_emploi():
    params = {
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
        'client_id': 'XXX',
        'client_secret': 'XXX',
        'scope': 'api_explorateurmetiersv1 explojob'
    }
    header = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
    url_co = 'https://entreprise.pole-emploi.fr/connexion/oauth2/access_token?realm=%2Fpartenaire'
    req_co = requests.post(url_co, params, header)
    wb = req_co.json()
    access_token = wb['access_token']
    print('reponse: ', wb)
    return access_token
```

That's working.

After, I want on my view, get  datas, but here, it's not working :

```
    def get_rome(param):
        access = login_explo_metier_pole_emploi()
        print('acces avec: ', access)
        params = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION', f"Bearer {access}")
        url = f"https://api.emploi-store.fr/partenaire/explorateurmetiers/v1/explorateurmetiers?libelle={param}&nombre=20&type=metier"
        req = requests.get(url, params)
        return req
```

It's returned an 401 error (Unauthorized).

Can someone help me please?

EDIT: [Documentation site](https://pole-emploi.io/data/api/explorateur-metiers-version-beta?tabgroup-api=documentation&doc-section=api-doc-section-rechercher-un-m%C3%A9tier-ou-une-comp%C3%A9tence)

Comment: first display `req.text` to see if there is some explanation

Comment: in question (not in comments) you could add link to documentation. Maybe it needs something else to access data. OR maybe it needs to activate special setting on web site to get token which gives access to data.